# How to achieve "depth" with a 3d css transform

Tags: css, css-transforms

I am trying to create a "perspective mockup" using CSS. There are a fair amount of tutorials on how to achieve this with 3D layers in Photoshop, but I would like to do it with CSS. Here is an example of what I am trying to achieve:
[image]

And here is the code (using the raw image, https://i.stack.imgur.com/xhs6l.png):

```css
#perspective {
  width: 400px;
  height: 500px;
  position: absolute;
  background-image: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/xhs6l.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -200px;
  margin-top: -250px;
  transform: rotate3d(360, 120, -90, 60deg) rotateZ(-30deg);
  box-shadow: -15px 15px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
```

```html
<div id='perspective'></div>
```

I am pretty close, but am unsure how to achieve the "depth" or "height" where the image looks raised. Zoomed in version of said "depth" where the image is repeated onto the sides:
[image]

P.S. if anyone knows the correct name for what I'm referring to as "depth", I'd love to know!

Comment: you the need shadow with different color?

Comment: @Saravana not the shadow, trying to get a raised card that has a thickness if that makes sense

Comment: Wait. I am playing around with that.

Comment: I believe the term you want is [extrusion](http://www.visual-3d.com/help/Chapter_6_Modify/6.10_Extrude.htm).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try adding three type of images to make 3D effects. Use `transform` property with rotation for images to get the desired result.

Answer reference [here](https://codepen.io/jrichmeier/pen/Mwdojy?editors=1100).

```css
.perspective {
    position: relative;
    width: 400px;
    height: 500px;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    transition: all 500ms ease-in;
    transform: rotateY(20deg) rotateX(60deg) rotateZ(-10deg);
    transform: rotateY(15deg) rotateX(50deg) rotateZ(-15deg);
    box-shadow: -40px 80px 80px -10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
    cursor: pointer;
    margin-right: 30px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 30%;
}

.perspective img {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 400px;
    height: 500px;
    transform: translateZ(16px);
}

.bottom,
.left {
    position: absolute;
    width: 400px;
    height: 500px;
    display: block;
    transition: all 1s linear;
    overflow: hidden;
    border-radius: 3px;
    transform: translateZ(16px);
    filter: brightness(80%)
}

.left {
    transform: rotateY(270deg) translateX(-1px);
    transform-origin: center left;
    width: 18px;
}

.bottom {
    transform: rotateX(90deg) translateY(15px) translateZ(-480px);
    transform-origin: bottom center;
    height: 18px;
}

.bottom img {
    transform: rotateX(180deg);
    width: 100%;
    height: 500px;
    left: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="perspective">
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/foDEYpB.png">
    <div class="bottom"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/foDEYpB.png"></div>
    <div class="left"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/foDEYpB.png"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: What about sphere?

Comment: Very impressive, thanks for this! Effect can be improved a fair bit with a simple `filter: brightness(80%)` on .bottom, .left - looks proper 3d.

Comment: @tolgraven good idea. updated

Answer (score 9):

Here is a hacky idea using multiple background to simulate such effect. The trick is to add 2 semi-transparent gradients to create the shadow effect then 2 other gradient to cut a small part of the corner to obtain the 3D shape.

The result may not be perfect for all the images:

```css
.wrapper {
  display:inline-block;
  perspective:1000px;
}
.box {
  margin: 50px;
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
  transform: rotate3d(360, 120, -90, 60deg) rotateZ(-30deg);
  background:
  linear-gradient(to bottom right,transparent 49%,#fff 52%) bottom right/14px 10px,
  linear-gradient(to top left,transparent 49%,#fff 52%) top left /10px 14px,
  
  linear-gradient(rgba(0,0,0,0.5),rgba(0,0,0,0.5)) 0 0px/10px 100%,   
  linear-gradient(rgba(0,0,0,0.5),rgba(0,0,0,0.5)) 100% 100%/calc(100% - 10px) 10px,   
  url(https://picsum.photos/id/1061/1000/800) center/cover;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper" >
<div class="box" >
</div>
</div>
```

With your image you can have a specific gradient like below:

```css
body {
  background:#ccc;
  
}
.wrapper {
  display:inline-block;
  perspective:1000px;
}
.box {
  margin: 50px;
  width:200px;
  height:250px;
  transform: rotate3d(360, 120, -90, 60deg) rotateZ(-30deg);
  background:
  linear-gradient(to bottom right,transparent 49%,#ccc 52%) bottom right/16px 10px,
  linear-gradient(to top left,transparent 49%,#ccc 52%) top left /10px 12px,
  
  linear-gradient(#efefef,#efefef) 100% 100%/calc(100% - 10px) 10px, 
  linear-gradient(-226deg,#222428 13px,#ff4946 13px,#ff4946 77px,#592D30 77px,#592D30 100px,#222428 100px,#222428 108px,#efefef 108px,#efefef 161px) 0 0px/10px 100%,      
  
  url(https://i.imgur.com/foDEYpB.png) center/cover;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="box">
  </div>
</div>
```